# ASP.NET Core MVC | Identity Insert Set To Off (but i didnt set it to off)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `Booking` model that should store details about a customer. The only notable thing about this model is that there's a property in there that stores the `CarId` that it gets from another view/model

Here's how it works: I click a "View Details" button on the Home/Index view then opens a partial view called "Details" and on that view, there's a "Book Now" button that brings up a booking form. This form is for the Bookings Model. Now, that "Details" view should pass the Id of the car that was selected into the Booking controller but I guess, it's either I don't know how to do it or it's just very difficulty.

Keep in mind, I'm very new to ASP.NET

Here is my `Booking` model class:

```
public class Booking
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public string LicenseIssueCountry { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Relationship Section For Car
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CarTypeId")]
    public virtual Car? Car { get; }

    [DisplayName("Pick Up Date")]
    public DateTime? PickUpDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Drop Off Date")]
    public DateTime? DropOffDate { get; set; }

    public double RentalDuration{ get; set; }
    public int rentalTotal { get; set; }

    public double RentalDurationCalculator(DateTime dDate, DateTime pDate)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = pDate - dDate;
        double rDuration = timeSpan.TotalDays;
        
        return rDuration;
    }

    public double TotalCalculator(int idGiven, double rDuration)
    {
        Car car = new Car();

        double rTotal = 0;

        if (car.Id == idGiven)
        {
            rTotal = car.CarPrice * rDuration;   
        }
        return rTotal;
    }
}
```

Here is my `BookingController`:

```
using CarRentals.Models;
using CarRentals.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CarRentals.Controllers
{
    public class BookingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProjectDbContext _dbx;

        public BookingController(ProjectDbContext db)
        {
            _dbx = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Booking booking = new Booking();

            return View();
        }

        // POST for Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Booking booking, int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //_dbx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bookings ON;");

                booking.RentalDuration = booking.RentalDurationCalculator((DateTime)booking.PickUpDate, (DateTime)booking.DropOffDate);
                booking.rentalTotal = (int)booking.TotalCalculator(id, booking.RentalDuration);

                _dbx.Bookings.Add(booking);
                _dbx.SaveChanges();

                //_dbx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bookings OFF;");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Booking` create view:

```
@model CarRentals.Models.Booking
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Left Column - Image -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @*<src ="~/images/cars/@Model.Cars.CarImage1" alt="Card Image" class="img-fluid">*@
            </div>
            <!-- Right Column - Form -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
                    @*<input asp-for="@Model.Car.Id" hidden />*@
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="FullName">Full Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="FullName" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="Country">Country</label>
                        <input asp-for="Country" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="LicenseNumber">License Number</label>
                        <input asp-for="LicenseNumber" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="LicenseIssueCountry">License Issue Country</label>
                        <input asp-for="LicenseIssueCountry" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                        <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                        <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control mt-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center" hidden>
                        <input asp-for="CarId" hidden /> @*value="@Model.Car.Id"*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="PickUpDate">Pick-Up Date:</label>
                        <input asp-for="PickUpDate" type="date" class="form-control mt-2" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <label asp-for="DropOffDate">Drop-Off Date:</label>
                        <input asp-for="DropOffDate" type="date" class="form-control mt-2" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-2 text-center">
                        <a asp-controller="CarList" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" @*asp-route-Id="@Model.Cars.Id"*@ />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your view code ?

Comment: @HarrY just made the change

Comment: You're trying to bind `[booking.]Car.Id` when I think you want `[booking.]CarId`. Just make sure you initialise the variable in your model `new Booking() {CarId = ...};`. Then study the generated html & network requests using browser developer tools.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks but remember i said on the Details view I pass a value for the car selected? that is coming from another model so what it is, is that I'm passing a property called ID from the car model and store it in the booking model and store it in CarId. Does that make a difference?

Comment: If you have an `asp-for="CarId"` then the mvc input tag helper will set the input value from the model (if you populate it), which you should see in the output html. Then the submitted value should be bound to your `Booking booking` argument. But you could pass the ID some other way if you want to.

Comment: However, beware of model over-binding. The MVC binder will allow any attacker to set any property on your `Booking` type. Your current implementation would allow me to post a `Car.SomeProperty=Value` and change a field in the car table, even if you don't want me to. Best practice is to create a new type for your view model, then copy the fields to your data model.

Comment: Regarding the title (because your assumptions are wrong): IIDENTITY_INSERT is OFF by default. It can only be set ON *for one table at a time*, and should be set OFF as quickly as possible when you're done inserting rows. If you need to specify the primary key, you need to configure your model not to use an IDENTITY column in the first place.